# Blocking content from all websites on Windows using keywords like xxx?

Tags: windows-10, website, parental-controls, web-filtering, content-type-association

I am already using DNS filtering to block porn websites but I still need to block porn content from all sites where not all content is porn. It would be a shame to have to block the whole site along with their legit content just to lose the porn. An example would be a torrent site, I would like to use a custom list of keywords to filter away torrents with, say, `xxx` in their titles. **What can I use to block content using a custom list of keywords from all sites?** Extra points for a method that I can password protect and throw away the password or other locking method, to make it cumbersome to circumvent.

Comment: Which operating system - Windows/Linux/Mac?

Comment: “What can I use to block content using a custom list of keywords from all sites?” - Deep packet inspection software that runs not on the machine, but on your DNS server (something like pihole), but I am not aware of any specific solutions that would allow cross content to be displayed. Regardless how you would accomplish that would require a software recommendation

Comment: The best way I've found to do this type of web filtering is using [Sophos UTM](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/unified-threat-management) as a router OS _(software appliance [download](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/downloads/utm-downloads))_, which is free to use for home users. Even if your router is capable of running OpenWrt, it would be difficult to do that type of web filtering. With Sophos UTM, web filtering decrypts all packets, scans them, removes/blocks content, then re-encrypts them with the UTM's master CA before sending them onto the downstream device.

Comment: _(cont'd...)_ A router OS [Sophos UTM, pFsense, etc.] requires a motherboard/server board with at least two ethernet ports [WAN, LAN] - I use a miniITX board within an In Win [Chopin](https://www.in-win.com/en/gaming-chassis/Chopin), running Sophos UTM within an [ESXi](https://www.vmware.com/products/esxi-and-esx.html) VM. The downside to web filtering is it will cut the ISP download throughput by ~50%, so it's recommended to only perform web filtering for specific downstream devices. In order to use WiFi with Sophs UTM, the WiFi card must match what Sophos uses in the UTM hardware router.

Comment: @JW0914 Oh dear. I take it that the Sophos Home installation does no such thing?

Comment: @Bricktop It's possible it's web filtering is advanced enough to do what you're looking for, however I've never used it - give it a try =] It will likely have no problem blocking adult sites, but adult content on a non-porn site may prove a bit tricky.

Comment: @JW0914 Installation failed.

Comment: @JW0914 that would still be a proper answer though. But. Does it work with tor browser too? Currently tor ignores all my DNS and Hosts file efforts.

Comment: @Bricktop I'm unsure if it's possible with Tor simply because of what Tor is - you'll want to refer to the Tor man pages, as Tor is completely different to configure in general.